# transfer data from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

How do this.
I want to transfer data
What I did:

js

```
    $("#add-ling-user-couch").click(function () {
    var CoucnId = $(this).data('couch-id');
    var data = { "CoucnId": curentUserId };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/AppUser/AddLink',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) { console.log(result) }
       // dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

cshtml

```
 @foreach (var a in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>@a.FirstName</td>

            <td>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    @Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = a.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Del", "Delete", new { id = a.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" })
                    <a id="add-ling-user-couch" data-couch-id="@a.Id">Add Link</a>
                </div>

            </td>

        </tr>
```

Contoller

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult AddLink(AddLinkViewModel model)
    {


        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { success = true, message ="Success" }    
        };
    }
```

I get some problem use it.

How can to do it other wise?
My way create more problem than it solve

it would work but I dont find it's correct

```
<form method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" value="@a.Id" name="CoucnId" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Sender" />
                            </form>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase _"I want to user can follow to Couch"_ - it's not clear what this means.

Comment: You need to read [ask], this question is a little confusing, has no definite problem statement or domain, and just 2 lumps of relatively unrelated code

Comment: It means: each other user can subscrube on coach on Web site. if user has subscribe he will be get notifification from coach. I changed My ask

Comment: Still it is not obious what the error is? Post the error (like something on client side (Developer Tools in Chrome are your friend), on the server...) Without that, this question lacks the context to provide an answer other than 42 (a joke referring to The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy)

Comment: yes, it's true. I was wrong before. My goal do button like a youTube subscribe. I would like have options like it.

Comment: I change. I could explain what I want. check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript:

```
$.post("/AppUser/AddLink", { CoucnId: curentUserId }, function (data) {     
   
    });
```

then in controller return partialview with modle:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult AddLink(int CoucnId)
    {
      fetch data and fill modle:
      return partialview("viewname",model);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.